# Javascript: Video.js not loading until hard refresh

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I'm creating a rails application that uses video.js to play videos. I am also using three other scripts to customize the player and activity on the page. My javascript imports are ordered as such:

```
= javascript_include_tag "video.js"
= javascript_include_tag "videojs-youtube.js", :defer => "defer"
= javascript_include_tag "videojs-overlay.js", :defer => "defer"
= javascript_include_tag "commentFeed.js", :defer => "defer"
```

My problem is that VideoJS is not loading the first time I navigate to a page. As a result, the three additional scripts that rely on the video.js script throw a bunch of errors. It's not until a hard refresh that everything starts to work properly.

Any idea why this is? I've attempted to defer the later three scripts until video.js loads, but it doesn't seem to help.

**How can I make sure the scripts run in order only after videojs is loaded?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: it turns out that the problem was related to how Rails uses Turbolinks to handle view changes.

My videojs object was not being destroyed as it should have been since `$(document).ready(...)` was not being called when expected, and therefore was not available on another page without a reload.

To solve this, I used the following code from [andrkrn](https://github.com/seanbehan/videojs_rails/issues/27#issuecomment-106225368) to listen for turbolinks load events and respond accordingly. Below are changes I made for it to work with Rails 5:

```
change = ->
    for player in document.getElementsByClassName 'video-js'
        video = videojs('video_player')
        console.log("Change, assigning video")

before_load = ->
    for player in document.getElementsByClassName 'video-js'
        video = videojs('video_player')
        video.dispose()
        console.log("before_load, disposing of video")

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', change)
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-visit', before_load)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced this issue and i used this to make videojs work.

```
change = ->
        for player in document.getElementsByClassName 'video-js'
            video = videojs(player)


    before_load = ->
        for player in document.getElementsByClassName 'video-js'
            video = videojs(player)
            video.dispose()


    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', change)
    $(document).on('turbolinks:before-visit', before_load)
```